# What else do you have to do to get Eclipse to recognize MinGW other than change the environmental variable "PATH"?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc

I'm installing Eclipse for C/C++ and am getting an error message that I believe I fixed.

[I get two errors saying the programs "g++" and "gcc" are not found in PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF4y0.png)

However, in the environmental variable "PATH", I have [a path going to a folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MA9k.png) containing programs called both "g++" and "gcc".  Why can't Eclipse find these programs? I cannot get any C to run without it.

Comment: Tried a restart?.. or at least a close/open of Eclipse since modifying PATH?

Comment: This sounds like an either/or scenario, but maybe try creating a MINGW_HOME variable: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_c_before_you_begin.htm&cp=9_0

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it has a problem with the space in your path.

Comment: This is normal Eclipse behavior, it always gives you all manner of strange error messages related to the tool chain. If you aren't constantly getting such problems, it is probably because you opened up another IDE by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the `PATH` variable to `gcc` and `g++` in the `Project Properties / C/C++ Build / Environment`.
In Windows, add it like this:

```
/path/to/compiler;${Path}
```